# Associating Metadata to a Polars Series

Tags: python-polars

I want to find a way to associate some metadata to a polars Series. For example, a unit for the value or if the data is a dependent or independent variable.

I want this metadata to be preserved over aliasing, reordering, etc... inside a dataframe, and I would also like to be able to declare how the metadata should be combined on operations between series. For example - two columns with units m, s respectively should have the unit m/s when the first is divided by the second.

I could do this by inheriting dataframe/series and implementing this stuff myself, but I would need to be very careful on tracking the column names and ordering over operations. I was wondering if there was some way to pull that kind of data (the mapping of columns -> columns) after an operation has been run?

Comment: This functionality doesn't exist. It *might* be readily implementable to simply have `metadata` as a child of `Series` and have that survive being put in a dataframe and pulled back out but to have the library convert to "m/s" etc would probably be pretty tricky unless all it does is manipulate strings such that division triggers metadata of one over metadata of other.

Comment: If series did have metadata, it would be nice to be able to register metadata operations to expressions, such that an expression can act on both the data and its associated metadata in a user-defined way.